# Docker - error during connect to port 2375

Tags: docker, vagrant, coreos

I'm unable to connect to the Docker daemon. I'm running on a Operating System CoreOS, when I run `docker info` I get the following

> error during connect: Get http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.37/info: http:
>   server closed idle connection

Before I had set the host to port 2375

`$ unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`

`$ unset DOCKER_CERT_PATH`

`$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375`

and Vagrant worked fine: I run `vagrant up` successfully
[image]

Why am I getting an error when I try to connect?

`docker version`

> Client:  Version: 18.04.0-ce  API version:    1.37  Go
>   version:  go1.10.1  Git commit:   3d479c0  Built: unknown-buildtime 
>   OS/Arch:  darwin/amd64  Experimental: false  Orchestrator:    swarm

coreos-vagrant/user_data

```
#cloud-config
    coreos:
      units:
        - name: docker-tcp.socket
          command: start
          enable: yes
          content: |
            [Unit]
            Description=Docker Socket for the API
            [Socket]
            ListenStream=2375
            BindIPv6Only=both
            Service=docker.service
            [Install]
            WantedBy=sockets.target
        - name: enable-docker-tcp.service
          command: start
          content: |
            [Unit]
            Description=Enable the Docker Socket for the API
            [Service]
            Type=oneshot
            ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl enable docker-tcp.socket
```

When I run `docker-machine ls`

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you run docker info from inside the VM?

Comment: @whites11 no it didn't

Comment: Why are you trying to configure remote access in the clear text as root without a password to the server?

Comment: @BMitch im just following the instructions on "Docker up and running" on page 36 https://github.com/TechBookHunter/Free-Docker-Books/blob/master/book/Docker%20-%20Up%20%26%20Running.pdf

Comment: Please take the time to secure the docker socket. Otherwise ssh is pointless, you'd be just as secure if you null out the root password and install a telnet server. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the CE for Mac Here is the link:
https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue like below;
goto your Docker Desktop -> Settings -> General and
then tick "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" checkbox